# How can I send JS string as xml document to user in Express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, express

I can't save string buffer as file and send it, because I'm using elastic beanstalk. I just have a string and I need to user can download this as xml document.

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  let xml = `<note>
                <to>Tove</to>
                <from>Jani</from>
                <heading>Reminder</heading>
                <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
            </note>`;
  //What next?
});
```

Comment: Set the content type header to the correct one (text/xml ?) And validate your whole xml document so that you send the correct res.

Comment: @Shilly when I do that I have a screen with xml code. I need downloading file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add content disposition header as attachment and content type as xml

```
Content-Disposition: attachment
```